# Pop-down Image Description Box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on my company's website and I know that I would like to create a team bio page similar to this one here: https://arch.iit.edu/people

I'm trying to recreate the description box appearing underneath the image when clicked on.

I'm trying to find the javascript/coding to help me do this; however I don't really know where to start as I did several searches under description box pop down, lightbox but it's not providing me what I really am looking for.

Can I ask for help on where to look to achieve this/how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what do you want to find exactly for your website. 
The jQuery slide methods slide elements up and down.
Take a look at this, on : [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp)

Tell me if it helps you

Regards, 
Adrian

Comment: This did! It's similar to what I want to do. I was able to get the slide function to work but do you know how I would get it so that the images will slide down cleanly when the description slides down? My slide is appearing behind the other profile images.

Comment: I also am trying to have the slide run across the browser as well, so I can do different columns with the text.

Answer (score 0):

That will be very simple but you can use just a begining.

```js
$('.holder').on('click',function(){
  $(this).find('.description').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.description {
  display:none;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.holder {
  width:140px;
  padding:6px;
  border:solid 1px #311;
  background-color: #000;
}

.holder img {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='holder'>
  <img src='http://bjstlh.com/data/wallpapers/65/WDF_1103100.jpg' width='120' height='120'>
  <div class='description'>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </div>
</div>
```